# Where to put methods available to all Marionette Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

So I have a method that I want to be available in all of my `ItemView`s and `CollectionView`s.

What I found after searching around was [behaviors](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.behaviors.md), but they aren't performing how I had hoped.

I would like to be able to define a method that I can call from any view and pass an argument.   In this case my implementation would put an image on the page, send a log statement, and remove it from the page after a certain amount of time.

Behaviors only seem to give me the ability to bind a method to an event, not call it from within existing methods attached to my view.

Right now I have

```
return Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    events: {
        "click .myButton": "addImage"
    },

    addImage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // code to add the image
    }
});
```

Then in the view, I have the behavior injected as `AddImage` with requirejs

```
    behaviors: {
        AddImage: {
            behaviorClass: AddImage
        }
    }
```

This works great if I use the click event, but I am still lacking a way to trigger it from an existing view method.  Perhaps with something like: `this.addImage(options)`.

Behaviors may not work like this, in which case I need a different way to make methods available to all of my views.

Comment: No, behaviors have another purpose. In your case there are two popular ways to follow : 1) extend Marionette.View with your methods 2) Create ItmeBaseView and CollectionBaseView extended from ItemView and CollectionView accordingly, add your methods to this Base views and extend all other Item and Collection views from these.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just extending the Marionette.View to give me the method visibility I needed.

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'underscore',
    'jquery'
], function(Backbone, Marionette, _, $) {
    _.extend(Marionette.View.prototype, {
        addElement: function() {...},

        removeElement: function() {...}
    }
});
```